# Inserting and updating the records in coredata using iOS

Tags: ios, database, core-data

When the ios mobile app launches first time, Based on user clicks am connecting to server.

**Let me explain in detail:**

1. Initially Connecting to server, parse the information and store into array. So,Am able to insert array of elements in to database.
2. Now the app launches next time, base on user clicks am able to to get the different array of elements.
3. Now am Able to retrieve the records from database and need to the check the latest records has been inserted in to database or not?

Please let us know, how to insert the records which is not available in database.

Comment: Iterate through your results, compare and discard or insert. It's pretty basic.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have an idea , first should compare the existing records and should insert into database.
could you please provide any sample. Because i am unable to insert the unique values in to database.

Answer (score 0):

Do your use CoreData with MagicalRecords?

Here is my code snippet of check if there is record existing and saving the data:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    ChatMessage* chatMessage = [ChatMessage MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"messageID" withValue:@198964 inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_rootSavingContext]];

    if(!chatMessage) //If there isn't any record with messageID 198964 then your programmatically create one
       chatMessage = [ChatMessage MR_createInContext:localContext];

    [chatMessage set...];
    .........


} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code snippet.
Please let us know the details about by using coredata basic methods only but not any third party files

Comment: Any one have an idea for the above query?